# Determine Windows version in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using Inno Setup to change the recycle bin in the OS. I need to make some cases for if the user is running Windows 7 or Windows XP. I try using:

```pascal
if not FileExists(winDir + '\System32\imageres.dll') then
  if not FileExists(winDir + '\System32\shell32.dll') then
    installError(3);
```

But it seems like it can't find `imageres.dll` or `shell32.dll` even though I've verified they exist. What am I doing wrong? Or can I check the Windows version another way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the [`GetWindowsVersionEx`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getwindowsversionex.htm) function. It fills a [`TWindowsVersion`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversionex) record:

```
TWindowsVersion = record
  Major: Cardinal;             // Major version number
  Minor: Cardinal;             // Minor version number
  Build: Cardinal;             // Build number
  ServicePackMajor: Cardinal;  // Major version number of service pack
  ServicePackMinor: Cardinal;  // Minor version number of service pack
  NTPlatform: Boolean;         // True if an NT-based platform
  ProductType: Byte;           // Product type (see below)
  SuiteMask: Word;             // Product suites installed (see below)
end;
```

There are a lot of other related functions. See below 'System functions' at [this page](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptfunctions.htm).

Answer (score 21):

In most Inno Setup sections (like `[Files]`, `[Tasks]`, `[Run]`, etc.) you can use the [`MinVersion` and `OnlyBelowVersion` common parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=commonparams).

```
[Files]
Source: MyDllForVistaAndNewer.dll; Dest: {app}\MyDll.dll; MinVersion: 6.0
Source: MyDllForOldWindows.dll; Dest: {app}\MyDll.dll; OnlyBelowVersion: 6.0
```

---

In Pascal Script, use the [`GetWindowsVersionEx`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversionex) function to find the Windows version number. Then compare the number against a specific [Windows version number](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes).

Here are few handy functions to check specific Windows versions:

```pascal
function IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(Major, Minor: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);
  Result :=
    (Version.Major > Major) or
    ((Version.Major = Major) and (Version.Minor >= Minor));
end;

function IsWindowsXPOrNewer: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(5, 1);
end;

function IsWindowsVistaOrNewer: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(6, 0);
end;

function IsWindows7OrNewer: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(6, 1);
end;

function IsWindows8OrNewer: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(6, 2);
end;

function IsWindows10OrNewer: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(10, 0);
end;

// Windows 11 has the same major.minor as Windows 10.
// So it has to be distinguished by the Build.
// The IsWindows10OrNewer condition is actually redundant.
// Once we have to test for Windows 11 using the build number, we could actually
// unify and simplify all the tests above to use the build numbers only too.
function IsWindows11OrNewer: Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);
  Result := IsWindows10OrNewer and (Version.Build >= 22000);
end;
```

Example of use:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  if not IsWindowsVistaOrNewer then
  begin 
    MsgBox(
      'This program was not tested on Windows XP and older, proceed with caution.',
      mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
  end;  

  Result := True;
end;
```

---

To test for server-editions of Windows, see:
[Checking for Windows Server 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53561203/850848)

---

*For version checking to work correctly on modern versions of Windows, make sure you always use the latest version of Inno Setup.*

Answer (score 7):

According to [the documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#difffiles), the parameters associated with each file can be directly tied to the OS version:

```
[Files]
Source: "{app}\WinNT2000XP.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; MinVersion: 0, 1
Source: "{app}\Win9598Me.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; MinVersion: 1, 0
```

"0" means never install; "1" means install on any version (i.e. version 1.0 or later).

Note: The above technique isn't limited to the [Files] section; MinVersion and OnlyBelowVersion can be used in most sections.