# how to check whether my operating system is windows xp or higher from inno

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno for creating a setup file. I'm stuck at detecting my OS type. Does anyone know how to check whether my OS is Windows XP or higher?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine Windows version in Inno Setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849917/determine-windows-version-in-inno-setup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GetWindowsVersionEx**  see this function in inno setup help file

Check this Code would work for you

```
procedure Initializewizard;
begin
{
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);



//windows version information
//5.0.2195 Windows 2000 
//5.1.2600 Windows XP or Windows XP 64-Bit Edition Version 2002 (Itanium) 
//5.2.3790 Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP x64 Edition (AMD64/EM64T) or Windows XP 64-Bit Edition Version 2003 (Itanium) 
//6.0.6000 Windows Vista 
//6.1.7600 Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2  
//6.2.9200 Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 
//Note that there is normally no need to specify the build numbers (i.e., you may simply use "5.1" for Windows XP).


  if (Version.Major = 5) and
     (Version.Minor = 0) then
  Msgbox('THIS IS Windows 2000 EDITION', mbInformation,MB_OK)
    if (Version.Major = 5) and
     (Version.Minor = 1) then
  Msgbox('THIS IS Windows XP or Windows XP 64-Bit Edition Version 2002 (Itanium)  ', mbInformation,MB_OK)
  if (Version.Major = 5) and
     (Version.Minor = 2) then
  Msgbox('THIS IS Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP x64 Edition (AMD64/EM64T) or Windows XP 64-Bit Edition Version 2003 (Itanium) ', mbInformation,MB_OK)

  if (Version.Major = 6) and
     (Version.Minor = 0) then
  Msgbox('THIS IS Windows VistaEDITION', mbInformation,MB_OK)

  if (Version.Major = 6) and
  (Version.Minor = 1) then
  Msgbox('THIS IS Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 EDITION', mbInformation,MB_OK)

  if (Version.Major = 6) and
     (Version.Minor = 2) then
  Msgbox('THIS IS Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 EDITION', mbInformation,MB_OK )
      }
  end;
```

**UPDATE:**
 Give a try to this statement. This Will store the required system info in a file.you can use **Loadstringsfromfile** to **tarraystrings** and then use how ever you want to.

```
Exec('cmd.exe', '/C systeminfo| findstr "OS Name: OS Version: OS Build Type: System Manufacturer: System Model: System Type: Processor(s): Total Physical Memory: Available Physical Memory: Virtual Memory: Max Size: Virtual Memory: Available: Virtual Memory: In Use:" |find /v /i "vmware" |find /v "Hotfix" | find /v "BIOS" |find /v "Locale" |find /v "Directory" |find /v /i "configuration"|find /v "Host Name"|find /v "Connection" |find /v "Date" |find /v "Boot" |find /v "Corporation" > "' + TmpFileName + '"', '', SW_HIDE,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to do this because XP is your minimum version of Windows required, then you can just use:

```
[Setup]
MinVersion=0,6.01
```

Which will prevent the installer from running on anything older than XP.

Alternatively you can do the same thing for individual files by using something like this:

```
Source: ...; MinVersion: 0,6.01
```

^ will install the file only on XP or above

```
Source: ...; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.01
```

^ will install the file only on pre-XP versions

Comment: Or if you need to test this from code, you may use e.g. the example shown in the [`GetWindowsVersion`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversion) function reference.