# How to get path in AppData\Roaming for Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I try to set path of my installation in InnoSetup to "....AppData\Roaming\MyApp"

My path in config -

```
DefaultDirName={userappdata}\CompanyName
```

And during installation, when i check my constants (in Evaluate Result window), i get:

```
{userappdata} - C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming
{app} - C:\ProgramData\CompanyName
```

How it works? How to install my app in AppData\Roaming\CompanyName???

My system is Windows 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inno Setup Installing to AppData\Roaming on Windows Vista/7 and newer, but Application Data on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480367/inno-setup-installing-to-appdata-roaming-on-windows-vista-7-and-newer-but-appli)

Answer (score 0):

I've created project again (using wizard) and it's ok!