# Check if the current OS is Windows 8.1 using Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to determine whether the current OS is Windows 8.1.

I know this could be solved analyzing the NT version number (**6.3**) of the current Windows version, but I don't know how to do it under Pascal script.

Pseudo-Code:

```pascal
// Occurs when the installer initializes.
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  if IsWindows81 then
    begin
      Result := IsKBInstalled('KB2919355');
      if not Result then
        MsgBox('Windows Update package "KB2919355" not found.', mbError, MB_OK);
      end;
    else
      begin
        Result := True
      end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8.1 is [Windows version](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes) 6.3.

The easiest is to check the return value of the [`GetWindowsVersion` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversion), which is `$MMNNBBBB` (**M**ajor, mi**N**or, **B**uild).

```pascal
function IsWindows81OrLater: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetWindowsVersion >= $06030000);
end;
```

If you want to check for Windows 8.1 only, use:

```pascal
function IsWindows81: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetWindowsVersion >= $06030000) and (GetWindowsVersion <= $0603FFFF);
end;
```

---

See also [Determine Windows version in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5849917/850848).