# Checking for Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, inno-setup, pascalscript

I created theses functions for installing some files on Windows Server 2003, I want to know if this is the correct way.

```pascal
function IsServer: Boolean;
var
  ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
  Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 5) and (ver.Minor >= 2) and Not IsWin64;
end;

function IsServer64: Boolean;
var
  ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
  Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 5) and (ver.Minor >= 2) and IsWin64;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show us what `UsingWinNT` does – Though you definitely do not need to check for "NT" – Inno Setup-made installer won't even start on non-NT system.

---

`IsServer64` will return true even on [Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, as it also has 5.2 version](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes).

To distinguish these, test `ver.ProductType = VER_NT_SERVER`.
See [How to programmatically tell the difference between XP 64 bit and Server 2003 64 Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15511021/850848)

---

```pascal
function IsWindowsServer2003_32Bit: Boolean;
var
  Ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Ver);
  Result :=
    (Ver.ProductType = VER_NT_SERVER) and
    (Ver.Major = 5) and (Ver.Minor = 2) and (not IsWin64);
end;

function IsWindowsServer2003_64Bit: Boolean;
var
  Ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Ver);
  Result :=
    (Ver.ProductType = VER_NT_SERVER) and
    (Ver.Major = 5) and (Ver.Minor = 2) and IsWin64;
end;
```

---

See also [Determine Windows version in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5849917/850848#38292498).